# Can I get response for POST method (Restful)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-services, rest, post

I want to make some request from iPhone app to my web service (Rails) and when is data procesed to get response with some string for example.

I read a lot about Apple's push notifications, but I need answer immediately and push notification can late.

I made POST request to my Rails app from my iPhone app, and it works.

**First question**(I got answer): But, can I get some string as response from Web service (Rails app)? 
**Second question**: When I got request from iPhone app, how to notifies some iPad device for example (with running app) quickly from my Rails web app? One solution is push notification, is there something faster and safer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want a text string you could do `render :text => 'Some string'`. If you want/need a more structured response then you should respond with JSON or XML.

Comment: When I put this render in my respond method in Rails app, I get HTTP/1.1 406 Not Acceptable response. How can I get this string on other side?

Comment: Or how to send JSON object from Rails app?

Comment: Just added one more similar question.